# Flash AS3 - URLLoader cant load binary data from different domain

Tags: actionscript-3

Two important points.
1 - SWF must have ability to loading binary data from any domain.
2 - SWF cant load policy XML file from url, cause upload form allows me only to upload swf files, so I cant include any other data.
I tried:

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
```

But it works only for SWF files.
I tried to embed policy XML file:

```
var dataXML:XML = 
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!-- http://www.foo.com/crossdomain.xml --> 
<cross-domain-policy> 
    <allow-access-from domain="*" /> 
</cross-domain-policy>;
```

But Security.loadPolicyFile(url:String) allows only to set file url, not data.
So my question is, how can I allow SWF to load binary files from different domains without having any additional file?
URLLoader code:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://differentdomain.com/binaryfile.dat");
var words:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
words.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY; 
words.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, prepareFile);
words.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loadError);
words.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, secureError);
words.load(request);
```

This will make an security error, if file is from different domain than SWF file.
Thanks for any help.

Its possible to get binary data from JavaScript using ExternatInterface in AS3 code.
Here is cross-browser library for reading files binary: [binary reader](http://blog.vjeux.com/2010/javascript/javascript-binary-reader.html) and later version [jDataView](http://blog.vjeux.com/2011/javascript/jdataview-read-binary-file.html)
Hope this will help someone.
Thanks to Jonatan Hedborg for idea.

Comment: To load a file from aaa.com you need to load the crossdomain.xml from aaa.com/crossdomain.xml else it may not work.

Comment: It looks like a joke for me. Any other language allows to download binary data from any place, but not AS3?

Comment: It's a security issue, and it's just how it is. The only way around it would be to set up a proxy server that you can relay your requests through. Also note that for example silverlight has an even stricter restriction on crossdomain loading, so it's not the only language with this quirk.

Comment: No solution if I cant upload anything other than only SWF file and also if I want my SWF to be indepedent from any additional php scripts on external servers? I dont understand - If wget on linux server, php , any download software or swf loaded locally can do it, why swf running under domain cant. We can load flash known media files and nothing more. I spent a real lot of hours on making first MIDI player in flash technology which can play midi and karaoke files from pasted url, and now its totally unuseful - I want it script/server independent.

Comment: It might be possible to hack something up with ExternalInterface and load the file via AJAX, but most people just set up a proxy server to load arbitrary files. There might be a service you can get for this so you don't have to set up your own? I'm not sure what you expect us to do about this - it's a security feature/limitation of flash, and not likely to change.

Comment: ExternalInterface and Ajax. I think you are right, it might solve problem, thanks for idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read this before : http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html

And you can use a proxy script, search on google/stackoverflow you'll find a lot of answers...

Comment: Ok, I will read, but I hope u mean script inside swf. I dont want make it dependent on any external scripts/servers. Also I cant upload anything other than only SWF file. Otherwise I would make intermediary download php file on same domain. I dont understand why programmers cant just set this setting inside code of swf file, but must use tricks with proxy? There is no way to embed this settings?

Comment: You misunderstand the problem, it is not a settings

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://wonderfl.net/c/gJXA

Some trick which works with any binary data from any domain, without need to use ajax or own proxy script (sometimes you dont have possibility to upload php scripts).

Comment: this uses Loader, not URLLoader, so I don't think you can access binary data (e.g. try changing the URL to an image URL)

Comment: @Penx You can use URLLoader with this script and also get binary data. Just try it one day. But I think theres a size limit of around 2 MB? Or maybe it was the server I grabbed data from doing the limit I'm not sure...

Answer (score 0):

Flash is control that most commonly used by HTML pages. As result it needs to follow security restrictions places on other (i.e. JavaScript) objects on the same page. 
Web pages use [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) security policy - objects on a page can't read data from domains different from domain of the current page.

There are cases when servers for other domains allow such access. I.e. in Flash case it is crossdomain.xml, similar policy file exist for Silverlight, there are several ways to handle it for JavaScript including [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Incorrect usage of ways to bypass same origin policy leads to [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) issues on your site/page that host your control which often leads to leaking personal information.

Answer (score 0):

I had to tackle a similar problem a while ago and managed to make use of `UrlStream` to load the target SWF's bytes at runtime.

gist: https://gist.github.com/1988661

Comment: I was looking for loading any binary data. I tested your script and it not work in my case.